# Can $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ imply $\nabla f\in H^{-1}(\Omega):=(H_0^1(\Omega))^*$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I'm reading a regularity proof in a monograph of PDE. A step of the proof may or may not be implied by the following statement (I don't know if it is true or not):

> Suppose $f\in L^2(G_R)$ where
>   $$
> G_R=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid x_n>0,|x|<R\}\quad\textrm{or  }\quad
> G_R=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid |x|<R\}.
> $$
>   Then $\nabla f\in H^{-1}(G_R)$ (component-wise), where $H^{-1}(G_R)$ is defined as the dual of $H_0^1(G_R)$.

Would anybody show me whether this is true or not?

Comment: How are you defining $\nabla f$?

Comment: @UmbertoP., it is in the sense of distribution.

Comment: In fact, you should use the space $H_0^1(G_R;\mathbb{R}^n)$

Comment: @Yongyong: that is why I write "component-wise".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Hölder, we deduce that 
$$\int\nabla f\cdot v\ dx:=
\int f\mathrm{div }v\ dx\leq\|f\|_{L^2}\|\mathrm{div }v\|_{L^2}
\leq\|f\|_{L^2}\|v\|_{H^1} $$ for $v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$, so $\nabla f\in H^{-1}$.

Comment: What is $v$? in the identity?

Comment: @Jack that is a test function in $H_0^1$.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Would you write the space explicitly? Do you mean $C^\infty_c(G_R)$?

Comment: $H_0^1$ is the completion of $C_c^\infty$ w.r.t. $H^1$-norm.