# Can $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ imply $\nabla f\in [(H^1(\Omega))^*]^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

This is closely related to a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1788066/9464) of mine. The only difference is the definition of $H^{-1}(\Omega).$

> Suppose $f\in L^2(G_R)$ where
>   $$
> G_R=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid x_n>0,|x|<R\}\quad\textrm{or  }\quad
> G_R=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid |x|<R\}.
> $$
>   Then $\nabla f\in H^{-1}(G_R)^n$ (component-wise), where $H^{-1}(G_R)$ is *defined* as the dual of $\color{red}{H^1(G_R)}$.

Would anybody show me whether this is true or not?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem

Comment: (and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/121786/characterizing-the-dual-of-w-0s-p )

Comment: @user1952009: I don't understand your comment. I'm not asking the characterization of dual of $H_0^1(\Omega)$ or the definition of the notation $H^{-1}$.

Comment: I don't think that the pairing $\int \nabla f\cdot v\, dx$ is well defined if $v\in H^1(G_R;\mathbb R^n)$. Integrating by parts one gets $-\int f\,\text{div}(v)\, dx +\int_{\partial G_R} fv\cdot n\, dS$. Why should the surface integral be well-defined if $f$ is only $L^2(G_R)$? It needs not have a trace on $\partial G_R$.

Comment: Anyway, the dual of $H^1(G_R)$ is briefly discussed in Adams's book on Sobolev spaces. Roughly speaking, the book says that while the dual of $H^1_0$ can be interpreted in distributional sense, the dual of $H^1$ cannot, because compactly supported smooth functions are not dense in $H^1$. (But to be honest, I must admit that I never quite understood this point. Luckily, I never had to face the dual of $H^1$ until now).

Comment: In the previous answer it is not required that $v\in H^1_0(\Omega)$. @Jack. $v\mapsto \int _\Omega  f \text{div} v dx$ always make sense as a function on $H^1(\Omega)$. This is the definition of $\nabla f$ as an element in the dual of $H^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: And your title say $f\in H^1$ while it is only $L^2$ is the question.

Comment: @JohnMa: Thanks for your comment. I edited it the title accordingly.

Comment: Do you have  a reference for "This is the definition of $\nabla f$ as an element in the dual of $H^1(\Omega)$"?